# Iintegrating trigger.io with paypal

Tags: paypal, trigger.io

I am unable to find any information related to integrating paypal express checkout with trigger.io would appreciate any help.

Comment: Opening a child browser window in trigger.io for paypal it does not return back values to return url after paypal payment is done. But works well on standard browser outside trigger.io

Answer (score 0):

I have never done this myself but one solution would be to use the child browser or "modal" to pass over the data into a secure modal window and allow the transaction to continue on paypal while still "inside" your app.

Comment: There seems to be an issue with that, I tried but seems after making the payment at paypal it does not return back to return url what works well on standard browser outside trigger.io